# ASP.NET MVC view model rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

**Question**:
How do I pull a simple model into a view as a strongly-typed object, using a controller?
**Problem**:
I create a simple class in a model, `newObject`. That class is referenced and passed to the view by my controller. However, I can't access the class in the view, using the Razor `@model` statement.
**Details**:
I'm a beginner learning ASP.NET and C#. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express on a Win7 machine. I started with an empty project, with folders and core references for MVC.
In short, I'm trying to get a handle on learning by doing.
I've followed some tutorials on [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net), but I'm trying to learn bare bones, without entity framework and that sort of thing.
**Code**:
Here's my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string objName = "Object1", objType = "Type1";
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MyObject newObject = new MyObject();
            return View(newObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and, the View. I can't access `newObject` in the view for some reason:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MyObject

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    This is a test page.<br />
    <!--Error on the next line-->
    @model.objName
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `@Model.objName`  with an uppercase 'M'. The lower case `model` is the "type" expected from controller. `Model` is the instance of the "type" passed.

Comment: That got it, thank you! Why does my intellisense not support "Model"? It shows "ModelBinders" etc, but there is no option for "Model"

Comment: Try closing out of VS 2013, reopen the project, and see if that helps. I have had that happen in 2013 just recently and it helped me.

Comment: Weird, that's what it was. Thanks again!